# zend auth conflicts with joomla's session

Tags: php, zend-framework, joomla

i m trying to integrate an application build in zend into a website that is build in joomla.

when i try to set zend's auth it gives me an error "session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()" since i'm getting logged in user's details using joomla's functions

is it possible to have zend's auth in parallel with joomla's session?

if not then is it possible to get logged in user's information without using any of joomla's functions(i think this is not possible)

how do i use joomla's already started session into my zend application?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with the filename of the Session cookie. If you need seperated Session try to set the Session options:

```
Zend_Session::setOptions(array(
    'name'                 => 'ZENDSession',
    'save_path'            => $appRoot . '/session',
    'remember_me_seconds'  => 864000
));

try
{
    Zend_Session::start();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //Exception
}
```

If you want to Authenticate against the Joomla UserDatabase, try this Zend_Auth_Adapter:
http://www.plainlycode.com/Joomla/Joomla-Authentication-Adapter-for-the-Zend-Framework.html